# Does unused weight from `ReservedXcmpWeight ` flow-over to extrinsics execution

Tags: weight, xcmp

We saw that the Cumulus pallet `xcmp-queue` has a configuration for `ReservedXcmpWeight` https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/polkadot-v0.9.26/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs#L174-L175
The `xcmp-queue` seems to be processed before any extrinsics in `setValidationData`, so I'm wondering if no weight of this ReservedXcmpWeight is used for actualy xcmp messages, will it flow over to be used for extrinsics execution or does it remain unused?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding `ReservedXcmpWeight` seems to be more of a cap in how much weight one block will be able to be filled by XCMP message execution than anything else.
Meaning that if no messages need to be served/executed for block X, then all that available block space is there to be filled by other executions.

Notice that there is a similar set up for DMP messages.

I would recommend reading [`service_xcmp_queue`](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/fb3837dcc9732ab8912eff51da9c86001d16206b/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs#L796) documentation for some more insight on, and I quote:

> Service the incoming XCMP message queue attempting to execute up to `max_weight` execution weight of messages

Comment: Yeah that was my intuition, thanks for the pointer.
In that case I'm wondering what would happen if the XCMP and DMP limits are hit, which are typically `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT / 4`.  Wouldn't the runtime then think it has `NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATION` amount of weight, usually 70%-75% of the `MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT`, when it only has 50% remaining ?